# how to set the default priority of a plugin programatically in elgg

Tags: elgg

How can I set the priority of a plugin by default, programatically, so that after installation and activation, it is shown  at the bottom of the plugin list automatically.

I know that we can set the priority in the administration section but how can we set that in code, so that when this plugin is installed on another site, by default it is at the bottom of plugin list.

I have tried:

```
elgg_register_event_handler('init', 'system', 'myplugin_init', 999999);
```

but it doesn't seem to work, and I can't find anymore documentation on it.

I'm using elgg 1.8.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this to set the priority last, but only setting the priority does not work until you clear the cache.

```
$plugin = elgg_get_plugin_from_id('myplugin');
$plugin->setPriority('last');
```

I have used the following function for setting the priority as it runs once per installation.
`run_function_once($functionname, $timelastupdatedcheck = 0)`

and have flushed the cache after that using `elgg_reset_system_cache()`

Answer (score 0):

Add a [priority dependency to your plugin's manifest](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/PluginDependencies) to keep it in proper order to overridden one.

There's no such feature like "always on bottom" since it would be problematic to handle multiple plugins that want to be on bottom of plugins list.

Comment: suggesting priority dependency only suggests the priority of the plugin, I want the plugin to be at the bottom of the plugin list by default after installation.